# Ajuda com Spread operator no react

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho um array de objetos salvo no meu state.

```
 const [rows, setRows] = useState();
```

sempre que crico em um botão ele dispara esta função

```
function processRow(value) {
   setRows(row=>[ ...row, row[value.rowIndex] = value.data]);
  }
```

no parametro da minha função ele me retorna o objeto com os dados, com o índice do objeto no state e o valor.
Oque eu gostaria seria que sempre que desse o `setRows` ele buscasse os dados e atualizace apenas o objeto na posição em que passei.
Porem ao invez dissso ele faz uma cópia do state e adiciona o valor abaixo.

```
0: {MotivoTroca: "Motivo", ContadorInicial: "Contador", DataHora: "Data hora"}
1: {MotivoTroca: "Motivo", ContadorInicial: "Contador", DataHora: "Data hora"}
2: {MotivoTroca: "Motivo", ContadorInicial: "Contador", DataHora: "Data hora"}
3: {MotivoTroca: "Motivo", ContadorInicial: "Contador", DataHora: "Data hora"}
```

retorno esperado serio

```
0: {MotivoTroca: "Motivo", ContadorInicial: "Contador", DataHora: "Data hora"}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A função do spread é justamente essa, ele vai manter tudo que já existe e adicionar o novo registro, se voce quer que não mantenha e apenas adicione o novo, remova o spread:

```
function processRow(value) {
   setRows([row[value.rowIndex] = value.data]);
  }
```

Comment: Isso o que você está fazendo também está errado, dessa forma o `setRows` irá receber um array com uma única posição. Além disso mutar o _state_ utilizando o valor atual como base, sem o uso de callback, pode causar uma _condição de corrida_.